# How to send a notification to a particular profile in Facebook custom story?

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-opengraph, facebook-stream-story, custom-stories

I have created a custom story to enable users to vote certain coffee shops in the town and I wanted to know if it possible to inform or notify the coffee shops that they have been voted.

For example, my story generates a content like "Martin has voted a coffee shop in XXX" where XXX is my application.

What I wanted is to notify a particular coffee shop, via its page profile or user profile, that it has been voted.

I have tried specifying the `profile_id` tag but it does **not** seem to work.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the Pages in your stories, that´s probably the only/best way: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.2#pages

Make sure you get it reviewed though, or it will only work for your own Pages: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#pagementions

Comment: Thanks for the answer luschn, I think it is the best way.

BR